# how do i print some string just below the loop simultaneously in python

Tags: python

i want to do multi process simultaneously, 
for example i want to print some string  just below the looping underway...

```
import time
from threading import Thread
print 'top'
def foo():   
  for i in range(1,10):
    sys.stdout.write(str('\r%s\r'%i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
timer = Thread(target=foo)
timer.start()
'''bottom'
```

i wanna the code above will looks like this

```
top
'''looping counter is underway'''
bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to block your main thread until your worker thread has finished.  For that you want the [join function](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)

```
import time
import sys
from threading import Thread
print 'top'
def foo():   
  for i in range(1,10):
    sys.stdout.write(str('\r%s\r'%i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
timer = Thread(target=foo)
timer.start()
timer.join()
print 'bottom'
```

Comment: it still the 'bottom' won't appears while the counter is looping.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to print 'bottom' then go back up to print the worker thread output unless you use a package like http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html [curses]

Answer (score 0):

Well, please read your favorite threading documentation.

You need to join() the thread

```
timer.join()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading